# splitting and merging std::list in C++

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

Why `std::list`s can not be split/merged in constant time? Aren't they just linked lists?

I m sure I am missing something. Can you please give an insight on the reasons behind that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a side-effect (some say a rather unfortunate one) of requiring `size()` to be constant-time. It is impossible to have both a constant-time `size()` and a constant-time `splice()` of sublists. Since all standard containers are required to have constant-time `size()`, this necessarily requires the sublist `splice()` to be linear.

Comment: I guessed that. But in C++98 size() is linea. why is splice linear as well?

Comment: @IssamT. I don't have access to the pure C++98 standard, but in its 2003 version, `size()` is marked as "should have constant complexity."